# JQuery .show animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got another problem with my code :)

```
        var limit = 15;

    $(document).ready(function() {
      var data = 'clients=&categories=&keywords=&limit='+limit;
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php?ind=work&op=get_list',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
          $('.list').html(data);
          $('.thumb').click(function() {
          var idz = 'id='+$(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'index.php?ind=work&op=get_work',
            data: idz,
            success: function (data) {
            $('.work').show('slow').html(data);
            }
        });
          });
        }
      });
    });
```

The HTML code is simple:

```
    <div class=\"center wide work\" style=\"display: none;\">
</div>
```

When I click on a div.thumb, all needed information is loaded with no problem. The problem is that there is no transition animation. Please help with that. Thanx in advance!

Comment: try `$('.work').hide().html(data).show('slow');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason I can think of is the element is already displayed, so try

```
$('.work').hide().html(data).show('slow');
```